# Word Representation of the Amount field in Acumatica In Report Designer

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb, dac, report-designer

Is there a way to convert the [cents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVkWw.png) into words?

This is what was used:
`[PXString(4000)] [PX.Objects.AP.ToWords(typeof(ARInvoice.curyOrigDocAmt))] [PXUIField(DisplayName="AmountToWordsEN")]`

[Where the code was used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2bsV.png)

Comment: It would take a bit more work than I had time to build out this morning, but you could enhance the attribute (or inherit into one of your own) to do this.  Look in the CodeRepository folder under PX.Objects/AP/Descriptor/Attribute.cs for the original code.  You will find a static class for LangEN that contains a method called ToWords.  With a bit of effort, you can leverage the existing code and code your own attribute to break the value into dollars and cents (both as whole numbers) and then apply the same logic to the cents portion that is applied to the dollars portion.